# Matlab calculate output

Tags: functions, matlab, laplace-transform, control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to write a matlab function that takes in a transfer function and the input so it can calculate the output. So far, based on [this information](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Transfer_Functions#Using_the_Transfer_Function) under  I have the following piece of matlab code:

```
function [output] = sys_response(system, input)
xs = laplace(input);
output = system*xs;    
end
```

But I don't think this is right because what if the input is a unit step u(t)? How would I detect that? I'm kind of shooting in the dark here, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to remember is that MATLAB does the analytical Laplace transform, so it will detect that you are providing an explicit unit step function. Normally the symbolic functions take the "normal" MATLAB functions as arguments, but internally change them over to the analytical versions. I think this is probably the same with the MATLAB unit step function.

Comment: I tried my function out by doing sys_response(s+1/(s^2+5s+6),ut) but it said `Undefined function or variable 's'.` Any idea how to fix that problem?

Comment: This page might help: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html   Also try: s=sym('s') on the previous line.

Comment: but I want the user to be able to call the function and just type in something like "s^2+s+1" so how do I detect that and/or do the laplace transform of that?